# MongoDb updateOne not updating results

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am trying to update a record inside a foreach loop. The loop runs and does not produce any errors, but nothing seems to update.

```
db.Collection1.aggregate({  
   $group:{  
      _id:"$RecordId",
      "DateUpdated":{  
         $max:"$DateUpdated"
      }
   }
}).forEach(function(doc){ 

    var recordId = doc._id;
    var date = new Date(doc.DateUpdated);

    db.Collection2.updateOne(
            { "_id" : recordId },
            { $set: {LastUpdate: date } }
        );     
});
```

Comment: Enable profiling and see what does it says. Also posting sample documents will be helpful

Comment: Have you verified that the `aggregate` query returns anything and your loop doesn't run with zero iterations?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 _id: ObjectId(id) ||  _id: ObjectID(id)
```

I think there should be this method in your mongodb library
either

```js
ObjectId(<your id>)
```

**or**

```js
ObjectID(<your id>)
```